# Bing Maps SDK - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, licensing, bing-maps

I'm currently using Silverlight Bing Maps SDK for my project. I was just wondering is it possible to use SDK for free if my imagery (map images) come from OpenStreetMaps? Or in that matter, any other (free) map imagery provider.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / terms of use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Bing Maps for free (whether you're using OpenStreetMap data or Bing Maps' own data) so long as you conform to http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html

Assuming it's for a commercial application, this basically means that you're limited to 125,000 sessions or 500,000 transactions per year. Any more than that and you'll have to have a licence. These limits don't apply if you're an educational/not-profit user, although there are some other limits on volume of geocoding requests etc.

Note that, just because you're using OpenStreetMap data doesn't necessarily mean that you don't need a licence - loading the map control itself counts as a "transaction", so if you do this more than 500,000 times in a year you'll still need to be licensed if you're using it for commercial purposes.

If you're not sure, try emailing maplic@microsoft.com

Comment: Here is the thing about licencing. We are selling web application to foreign government which will use our application to inform public about traffic state on their highways (traffic jams, weather information's and etc). The web page will be free and public users won't get charged for viewing traffic information's. I just cant get in touch with anyone from MS who can get us any concrete information's. I'll try emailing them again. Tnx for your answer. I would vote it up but i don't have necessary reputations points :(