# Bing map license for on premises application

Tags: licensing, bing-maps

I saw this [bing map license post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736146/bing-maps-sdk-silverlight), it is very helpful. However I think that I still need to understand a little more here. We are going to build one application which would be deployed on customer on premise network and would be managed by customer. Our application would use Bing Map API, in this case, it should be the customer who bought our product to get the Bing map license instead of Software Vendor which is us. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the relationship you have with Microsoft, the two options can be used in my opinion.

- **You are the reseller:** perfect if you have multiple customers and you want to simplify the process for them, you have to discuss about it with Microsoft
- **Your are not a reseller:** the customer contracts directly with Microsoft and a contract will occur for each customers

In order to get you the best answers, I highly recommend that you reach this official mail: [maplic@microsoft.com](http://maplic@microsoft.com)

Comment: thanks very much for the answer. We will follow up with Microsoft then.